# html: wav audio file won't play localhost

Tags: html, audio, wav

My `index.html` file contains these lines of code:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="tts.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

This is my working directory
[image: Working Directory]

This is what my html page audio looks like. It's greyed out even though the file exists:
 [image: Audio]

I get this error message `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :3000/tts.wav`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What web server do you use? How did you configure it?

Comment: port localhost:3000

Comment: But what do you use for the web server?